# ASP.NET ASPX Debugging

Tags: asp.net, debugging

What's the best way to systematically debug the aspx pages ( not C# or Vb.NET managed code). Sometimes a small syntax or semantic error in aspx page displays:

> Internal server error or something similar

and I had to comment the last changes step by step to find out the error.

Is there any other systematic way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20100420054306/https://help.godaddy.com/topic/216/article/3430#IIS6) might help (however you should remember to switch the application into `Release` mode before launching it on the production environment).

Comment: Backup https://web.archive.org/web/20100420054306/https://help.godaddy.com/topic/216/article/3430#IIS6.  Doesn't seem that helpful still though.